# UnicodeEncodeError while using spark-submit and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, hadoop, beautifulsoup

I keep getting a UnicodeEncodeError in Python 2.7 when I submit a job to spark 1.6, hadoop 2.7 but **I do not get the same error when I am executing the same code line by line on the pyspark shell**.

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to get all the tags and getting the text from them using this line of code:

`[r.text for r in BeautifulSoup(line).findAll('ref') if r.text]`

I have tried the following things:

1. Set the `export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf8"`
2. Use `r.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`
3. Also tried to apply `sysdefaultencoding('utf-8')`

Could please someone tell me how to fix it? Below is the error stack:

````
"/hdata/dev/sdf1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/harshdee/appcache/application_1551632819863_0039/container_e36_1551632819863_0039_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/home/harshdee/get_data.py", line 63, in get_as_row
    return Row(citations=get_citations(line.content), id=line.id, title=line.title)
  File "/home/harshdee/get_data.py", line 47, in get_citations
    refs_in_line = [r.text for r in BeautifulSoup(line).findAll('ref') if r.text]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 274, in __init__
    self._check_markup_is_url(markup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 336, in _check_markup_is_url
    ' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/warnings.py", line 29, in _show_warning
    file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/warnings.py", line 38, in formatwarning
    s =  "%s:%s: %s: %s\n" % (filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 21-28: ordinal not in range(128)```
````

Comment: Python 2.7 is now rather old, but have you tried to convert everything to unicode: `...findAll(u'ref')`?

Comment: No, I haven't I will give it a try!

Comment: `[r.text for r in BeautifulSoup(line).findAll(u'ref') if r.text]`: tried this but gave me the same error @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem on my own. I think the problem was in the representation of the string.

For this, I used the `repr` function which returns the object representation. In other words, it basically returns a `string` which is uniformly encoded.

I applied this on the `line` variable.